# Labeling points imported from csv

Tags: tikz-pgf, csv

I have a csv file consisting of two columns corresponding to the x and y coordinates of a point cloud. Since it is possible to label a point in a tikzpicture environment by

```
\coordinate (1) at (0,0); # from now one simply has to write (1) instead of (0,0)
```

I was wondering if it is possible to import the points from the csv file and labeling them automatically with their appropriate row number in the file.

Comment: Yes that's what pgfplots does. You can also use `plot` from TikZ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, I use `readarray` to absorb and compose the data.  I label the coordinates as `R\i` where `\i` is the local row number.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{readarray,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata}
-4,16
-3,9
-2,4
-1,1
-.5,.25
0, 0
.5,.25
1, 1
2, 4
3, 9
4,16
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\readdef{mydata}\myrecorddata
\readarray\myrecorddata\xypts[-,2]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\thedamnedline{}% INITIALIZE
\foreach\i in {1, ..., \xyptsROWS}{
  \coordinate[label=\textcolor{red}{R\i}](R\i) at (\xypts[\i,1],\xypts[\i,2]);% DEFINE/LABEL
  \fill[red] (R\i) circle (2pt);% ADD CIRCLE AT EACH COORDINATE
  \ifnum\i>1\relax\xdef\thedamnedline{\thedamnedline -- }\fi% COMPOSE INTERCOORDINATE LINKS
  \xdef\thedamnedline{\thedamnedline (R\i) }% COMPOSE COORDINATES SEQUENTIALLY FOR LINE
}
\draw\thedamnedline;% DRAW \thedamnedline (PREVIOUSLY COMPOSED)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]